# Twitter Bootstrap - resizing the browser's window - causes the layout element's positions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've just started using the Twitter Bootstrap and can't use its all features :)
The problem is that my elements (for example top, bottom menu and elements from right corner) chaotically changes their places when I resize the browser's window.
As I understood the TB should take care of it automatically when you place elements inside common **container** and provide **class="row-fluid"**
But I've no luck resolving this issues.
The demo template have been placed here http://www.01kuzma.tk/
Waiting for some help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues I see here:

You are assigning fixed dimensions on the selector #nav. You cannot use fixed dimensions like this in a fluid layout. If you remove this, you will see things start behaving correctly.

Also, you are using top on #h_line. This should be margin-top (again try not using fixed dimensions, use% instead). Keep in mind that top property specifies how far positioned the elements top margin edge is whereas margin-top applies to the entire block element.

Let me clarify one thing, it's not that you can't use fixed dimensions altogether, but rather that if you do you will have to declare different values at each breakpoint (via @mediaqueries).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Have I understood correctly that you are talking about #nav{height:55px}? I've removed this line now and changed the #h_line to `#h_line{
    position:relative;  
    margin-bottom:-1%;
    z-index:2;}` (it's done to overlap the slider with horizontal line), but still everything is crushing :(  P.S. I just want to make layout fluid as it's done in TB example: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html

Comment: Also blocks: Left_En, Right_En and Top right blocks collapses :( They have only classified only with colour property

Comment: Found here some additional CSS rules for `.navbar .nav.menu.nav-pills*` looks that the problem with menu have been solved (if it's crossbrowser solution). Problems only left with 3 blocks...